# Robotium test case for android

Tags: android, testing, android-tabhost, robotium

I am new to android test cases(Robotium).
I want to write test case for unlock screen and panel(Button) or Detail(Button) or Launcher icon (Button) using Robotium test case. After i want to Tap on my application icon..

please any one help me..

Answer (score 2):

You question is similar to this:

[How to write test cases for the home screen activity using robotium in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831154/how-write-test-cases-for-the-home-screen-activity-using-robotium-in-android)

Is there a reason you have to automate the lock screen?

Robotium is really build to test one package and not span multiple packages and activities in the same test suite.
You should easily be able to launch you app and test it with robotium, if you can live without automating the lock screen.